# I want to pass two functions in onChange attribute in id password in input field. I want to pass event also and confirm() function also. (ReactJs)

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass two functions in `onChange` attribute in id password in input field. I want to pass event also and `confirm()` also.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './Form.css'
import validator from 'validator'


const Form = () => {
    
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [number, setNumber] = useState('')
     

    const confirm = (value) => {
        if (validator.isStrongPassword(value,{
            minLength : 8, minLowercase : 1, minUppercase : 1, minNumbers : 1, minSymbols : 1
        })) {
            
        }
    }

    const CheckNumbers = () => {
    var pass = password.toString()
    var confirmPass = confirmPassword.toString()
    var num = number.length;
    
    if((pass === confirmPass) && (num === 10)) {
        return <button type="submit" className="submit_button" >Submit</button>
    }else if( (pass!==confirmPass) || (num !== 10)) {
        return <button type="button" disabled={true} className="submit_button">Submit</button>
    }
}

    return (
        <>
            <p className="heading">Login Form</p>
            <form action="submit" className="form">
            <input type="text" required value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g , ""))}/>
            <input type="email" required value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
            <input type="password" required id="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="password" required id = "confirmPassword" name={confirmPassword} onChange={(e) => confirm(e.target.value)}/>
            <input type="number" required value={number} onChange={(e) => setNumber(e.target.value)}/>
            <CheckNumbers />
            </form> 
            
        </>
    )
}

export default Form
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const handlePassword=(event)=>{
  //here you will get your complete event
   console.log(event)
 
    confirm(event.target.value)

}
<input type="password" required id = "confirmPassword" name={confirmPassword} onChange={(event) => handlePassword(event)}/>
```